# конструктор класса объекта с параметрами, являющегося членом другого класса

Tags: c++, конструктор

существует класс (A), содержащий в качестве члена экземпляр другого класса (B), с конструктором, содержащим параметры. Как правильно создать и инициализировать член класса (Б) не в процессе создания (А), а в его конструкторе, после вычисления необходимых параметров?

```
struct B{
  ...
  B(int x, int y){..}
  ..
}

struct A{
  ..
  B b(0,0); //<-- здесь я создаю объект класса B, который никогда не будет использоваться, как этого избежать?
  ..
  A(..){
    ..
   calc_params(p1,p2);
   B b=B(p1,p2); 
 }
}
```

Comment: Вопрос не понятен. Создавайте экземпляр там где нужно. не создавайте где не нужно. В чем сложность то?

Comment: Напишите пожалуйста свой код вместо моего, как бы вы это сделали

Answer (score -2):

Как минимум вместо `struct {...}` написать `class A {...};` и `class b {...};`

```
int p1 = 10, p2 = 20;

void calc_params(int& p1, int& p2) { }

class B {
public:
    B(int x, int y) { }
    B() { }
    void SomeAction() { }
};

class A 
{
private:
    B* b; 
public :
    A() 
    {
        calc_params(p1, p2);
        b = new B(p1, p2);
        b->SomeAction();
    }
    ~A()
    {
        if(b != nullptr)
            delete b;
    }
};
```

Comment: Это влияет только на дефолтный доступ к полям/родителям (`public` или `private`), больше ни на что.

Comment: Вы тоже создаете объект B дважды

Comment: @Данила_, вот так попробуй.

Comment: Это конечно проблему решает. Можно использовать также умный указатель, или что-то вроде дополнительного метода set_params(P1,P2). Но все же, есть ли способ вызвать 1 раз конструктор класса члена, размещаемого на стеке отложено, с параметрами, которые будут известны позже?

Comment: @Данила, чтобы вызывать конструкторы отложенно, применяют ссылки и указатели. Указатель - все равно, что неинициализированная переменная. Чтобы что-то использовать, надо его инициализировать. Это если тип не ссылочный. Если ссылочный, то его можно оставлять nullptr. Потому, что тип значения не может иметь тип null / nullptr. Так же, как и int нельзя присвоить Null и инициализировать позже (хотя в си в принципе можно, но так делать не рекомендуется, потому что в эту переменную может попасть мусор, любое число). Класс - это тоже тип значения, потому что может создаваться в стеке без указателя.

Comment: @Ivan Silkin спасибо вам большое за такой подробный и обстоятельный ответ!